# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException when copying WPF application to an other computer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, bitmap

I've got an WPF project, which works on my computer just fine. However, when I copy in to an other computer or a virtual machine, it crashes with following error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception.' Line number '38' and line position '97'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The device is not ready.
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The device is not ready.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.InitializationGuard(XamlType xamlType, Object obj, Boolean begin)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The images are embedded into the project file as global resources.

Any suggestions what could cause this?

UPDATE: I've localized the issue:
When I use following code

```
    <Image Margin="148,80,144,114">
        <Image.Source>
            <ImageSource>hexagon4.png</ImageSource>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

the application transfers fine.

When I  use

```
<Image Margin="148,80,144,114" Source="{DynamicResource myimage}"/>
```

the app crashes after the transfer

Here's the project that reproduces the error: [download](http://www.iathao.com/tmp/leartWPF.zip)

Comment: Aren't you using absolute paths in your code? Could you show us your code for those images?

Comment: I've added some code to illustrate the issue

Comment: And how do you set that resource?

Comment: in Expression Blend Source->Convert to new resource->entered key name and place. The app crashes for every storage place I choose

Comment: I think you're confusing two types of resources: XAML resources (what `DynamicResource` reads) are not the same as .Net resources (what I think Blend produces).

Comment: blend generated the references automatically, and it works on my own machine. If the resource reference was wrong, it should always crash. I've added a project that generates the problem to the description